# How to "lazy load" ( "require modules" ) coffeescript using meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

Coming from a node.js background i'm used to have many small files ( with one function per file ) which contains their own "scope" and then just require then as needed.

Is there a "workaround" to make this happen on meteor?

I saw the new beta version will allow "modules" ( exports / "require" ) from ecma6, but i would definitely prefer writing coffee script over ecma6.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the environment supports the syntax, you can always inject raw js into your coffeescript with backticks, eg `\`import * as foo from 'bar'\``. Also, if you plan on reusing any of that code in the browser make sure you either concatenate it or use `http2` exclusively.

Comment: have you tried this with meteor 1.3 ? i tried and didn't work out, maybe i did something wrong? any chance of making an example ?

Comment: Backticks are being considered for 1.3. See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5788).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions on how to use ES2015 modules with meteor. I'm posting this basically link-only answer because it took several iterations of refining google searches to stumble across it. So saving anyone else the trouble, [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/wip-release-1.3/packages/modules) is it.

Note that using this strategy on the client will still generate a *ton* of relatively expensive `http` requests which is problematic, especially on mobile. Even using ES2015 modules I recommend using a build process to concatenate all those little files into fewer logically grouped ones.